# MySQL - Percentage of total with multiple line

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I got a [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5MSD.png) with multiple market details and I'd like to get the percentage of the total sales in a new column like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCxPT.png).
I tried the following code but it doesn't work.

```
Select Market, Sale, Sale*100/t.s as %total
from mytablename
cross join (select sum(Sale) as s from mytablename
group by Market
```

Can anyone can help?

Thanks

Comment: Really bad idea to include '%' in an alias

Answer (score 2):

Use a subquery an aggregation functions:

```
Select t.Market, sum(t.Sale), sum(Sale)*100.0/total.s as `%total`
from mytablename t cross join
     (select sum(Sale) as s from mytablename) total
group by t.Market;
```

Comment: I got an error: Unknown column 't.Market' in 'field list' but I have the Market column in my data.